# Can I get the string index and column names for a given position in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Given something like the following

```
>>> breakfast = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2, 3], 
                              [1, 2, 3], 
                              [3, 0, 2]], 
                             index=['Thuy', 'Kana', 'Malcolm'],
                             columns=['eggs', 'bacon', 'pancakes'])
>>> breakfast
         eggs  bacon  pancakes
Thuy        2      2         3
Kana        1      2         3
Malcolm     3      0         2
>>> breakfast.iloc[1,1]
2
```

Is it possible to also see that the `(row, col)` pair for `breakfast.iloc[1,1]` was `('Kana', 'bacon')`. This would be convenient for a large data frame I have that is diagonally symmetric. I am using `.iloc` to only iterate over one half, but I lose the row and column information in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define your own function to return you the index and column label values by ordinal position:

```
In[96]:
def row_col(index_pos, column_pos):
    return (breakfast.index[index_pos], breakfast.columns[column_pos])
row_col(1,1)

Out[96]: ('Kana', 'bacon')
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that the `index` and `columns` attributes of the DataFrame are themselves Series. So my solution was `breakfast.index[y]` or `breakfast.columns[x]` where `y` and `x` are integers. That is how you get the corresponding string for a given location.